# Get number of revisions for a .docx file

Tags: ms-word, docx

Is there a way to get the number of "revisions" of one docx ?

[image]

Comment: Why does your question precise: separated by commas ? If you can do it for one word document, you should be able to do it for many and separate the ouptut with a comma.

Comment: What's your programming language ?

Comment: I have no experience in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docx is a zipped format (see [Tag Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/docx/info))

You can find this information in `docProps/core.xml`:

For example:

```
<cp:revision>2</cp:revision>
```

means that they have been two revisions.

Comment: Thanks. I want to be able to get the number of revisions for several thousand files as comma seperated values. If you could be more specific, I would really appreciate it. I have no programming experience.

Comment: You can learn to do that. Stackoverflow is not a site to write specific code for you, but to ask questions that could be helpful for anyone. You can use https://www.codersclan.net/ if you want to have a specific task done

Comment: Don't have the money for codersclan.net unfortunately. Thought it was a simple task. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Of course it's a simple task. But SO is not to solve your simple tasks.

Comment: Some people might want to help, others might not. No complaints.